# What does this mean "if (!(i % 10) && i)"

Tags: c

What does this line of code mean, I found this in this piece of code:

```
void simple_print_buffer(char *buffer, unsigned int size)
{
    unsigned int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < size)
    {
        if (i % 10)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if (!(i % 10) && i)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("0x%02x", buffer[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What do *you* think? Please [edit] your question to share your own thoughts.

Comment: The `!(i % 10)` remainder when `i` is divided by `10` should not be equal to `0` and the part `&& i` means `i` should not be equal to `0`

Comment: And for understanding complex expressions better, I suggest you split them into smaller and simpler expressions, and continue this until nothing can be split further. For example `!(i % 10) && i` can be split into `int t1 = i % 10; int t2 = !t1; int t3 = t2 && i;`. If you understand the separate operators, then doing like this might make it easier to understand the whole complex expression.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX: `!(i % 10)` is true when the remainder of `i` divided by 10 **is** equal to 0.  I agree it is confusing and should be rewritten as `i % 10 == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

`i % 10` means `i modulo 10` or calculates the last digit of the integer `i`.  Then operator precedence tells you the `!` is applied next which means `not`, and in this case, if the last digit is `not 0`.  `&&` means `and` so the if statement is executed if both left (already discussed) and right side are `true`.  Right side `i` means that `i` is `not 0`.

You can refactor the code by using a `for` loop, as both branches of the `if` statement does `printf` you can use a conditional value instead of a conditional statement:

```
void simple_print_buffer(char *buffer, unsigned size) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(i) printf(i % 10 ? " " : "\n");         
        printf("0x%02x", buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the two `if` statements is to print the separator before the next number. The loop outputs 10 bytes per line in hex format, there should be no initial separator, hence no output if `!i`, and the separator should be a space between numbers except every 10 numbers where the separator is a newline.

`%` is the modulo operator: `i % 10` computes the remainder of the division of `i` by `10`.

The test `if (i % 10)` means *if `i` is not a multiple of 10* and the next one `if (!(i % 10) && i)` means *if `i` is a multiple of 10 and `i` is not zero*.

The code can be simplified as:

```
void simple_print_buffer(const char *buffer, unsigned int size) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i % 10) {
            printf(" ");
        } else
        if (i) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("0x%02x", buffer[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Or even simpler:

```
void simple_print_buffer(const char *buffer, unsigned int size) {
    if (size) {
        static char const separator[] = { ' ', '\n' };
        printf("0x%02x", buffer[0]);
        for (unsigned int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            printf("%c0x%02x", separator[!(i % 10)], buffer[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This last version could easily be changed to produce no output if `size == 0`, not even an empty line, which may or may not be expected.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: indeed! I removed the paragraph to avoid confusing the reader, but many programmers are not aware of the possibility of negative remainders for negative operands.

Comment: `" \n"[i % 10 == 0]` is elegant but it's easy to miss the space (I assumed you were switching between `\n' and `\0` on first glance).  Maybe introduce a variable `static const char sep[] = { ' ', '\n' };` so you can write space as ' '?  Then use it like this: `sep[!(i % 10)]` You can do this inline with a initialization but it's a little messy.

Comment: Compiler will do it for you but I would move the declaration outside the loop.  It is another way to tell reader that it's constant over the loop.

Comment: @AllanWind: the definition is `static`, there is no runtime overhead regardless of the scope.

Comment: Hence why I said the compiler will take care of it for you.

Answer (score 1):

`!condition` is true when `condition` is false or 0.

First condition is equal to `(i % 10) == 0`. Second condition is equal to `i != 0`.

`&&` means that the `if` clause is executed when both conditions are true.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers already explain it, but this code might help understanding:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0;  i<50; i++)
    {
        printf("i: %d    i mod 10: %d    !(i mod 10): %d    !(i mod 10) && i: %d \n",
                i,       i%10,        !(i%10),        !(i%10)&& i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
i: 0    i mod 10: 0    !(i mod 10): 1    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 1    i mod 10: 1    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 2    i mod 10: 2    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 3    i mod 10: 3    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 4    i mod 10: 4    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 5    i mod 10: 5    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 6    i mod 10: 6    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 7    i mod 10: 7    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 8    i mod 10: 8    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 9    i mod 10: 9    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 10    i mod 10: 0    !(i mod 10): 1    !(i mod 10) && i: 1 
i: 11    i mod 10: 1    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 12    i mod 10: 2    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 13    i mod 10: 3    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 14    i mod 10: 4    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 15    i mod 10: 5    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 16    i mod 10: 6    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 17    i mod 10: 7    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 18    i mod 10: 8    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 19    i mod 10: 9    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 20    i mod 10: 0    !(i mod 10): 1    !(i mod 10) && i: 1 
i: 21    i mod 10: 1    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 22    i mod 10: 2    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 23    i mod 10: 3    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 24    i mod 10: 4    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 25    i mod 10: 5    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 26    i mod 10: 6    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 27    i mod 10: 7    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 28    i mod 10: 8    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 29    i mod 10: 9    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 30    i mod 10: 0    !(i mod 10): 1    !(i mod 10) && i: 1 
i: 31    i mod 10: 1    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 32    i mod 10: 2    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 33    i mod 10: 3    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 34    i mod 10: 4    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 35    i mod 10: 5    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 36    i mod 10: 6    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 37    i mod 10: 7    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 38    i mod 10: 8    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 39    i mod 10: 9    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 40    i mod 10: 0    !(i mod 10): 1    !(i mod 10) && i: 1 
i: 41    i mod 10: 1    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 42    i mod 10: 2    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 43    i mod 10: 3    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 44    i mod 10: 4    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 45    i mod 10: 5    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 46    i mod 10: 6    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 47    i mod 10: 7    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 48    i mod 10: 8    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0 
i: 49    i mod 10: 9    !(i mod 10): 0    !(i mod 10) && i: 0
```